# Requirejs: Load a module where the require('path/to/module') comes from a variable?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require

Is it possible to do this:

```
 define( function( require ){
        var path = 'json!/app/pagelang/login';
        var appLang = require(path),
```

instead of this:

```
 define( function( require ){
        var appLang = require('json!/app/pagelang/login'),
```

from my tests it's not possible because it results on the following console error:

**Uncaught Error: Module name "json!/app/pagelang/login_unnormalized2" has not been loaded yet for context: _**

Comment: I think you are talking about different modules. Please provide more information about application architecture or more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just have to change your syntax a little:

```
define( function( require ){
  var path = 'json!/app/pagelang/login';
  require([path], function(appLang){
    // Do stuff with appLang…
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually "no", your second snippet uses [sugar syntax](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar) which uses regular expressions to rewrite your code "behind the scenes" to be something like:

```
define(['json!/app/pagelang/login'], function (appLang) {
  // appLang available
});
```

The same mechanism can't work when the module name is a variable because the dependencies block needs concrete module names, not variables. Because of that, as noted by @idbehold you need to use a proper asynchronous form of inlined `require`:

```
define(function (require) {
  var path = 'json!/app/pagelang/login';
  require([path], function (appLang) {
    // appLang available
  });
});
```