# Requirejs loading modules where paths come from variables

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've the following situation

// THE MAINMODULE

```
define(function(require){
   var module_A = require('PATH/TO/MODULE/A');

   var MODULE_A = new module_A();
})
```

// THE MODULE A

```
define(function(require){
    var DEPENDENCY_PATH = "PATH/TO/" + GLOBALVARIABLE + "/FOO/BAR";

    var DEPENDENCY_MODULE = require(DEPENDENCY_PATH);

    var A = function( options ){
       this.age = option.age;
    }

    return A;
})
```

Then, based on some examples, i come up with the following but the problem is that the module is never returned to the MAINMODULE which loads MODULEA as a dependency

```
define(function(require){




   var DEPENDENCY_PATH = "PATH/TO/" + GLOBALVARIABLE + "/FOO/BAR";

   var _a;
   require([DEPENDENCY_PATH], function(DEPENDENCY_MODULE){
       var A = function( options ){
          this.age = option.age;
       }

       a_ = A;           
       return A;

   })

   //HOW CAN I RETURN A?
   return _a;


})
```

Any help please?

This is a similar question but the loaded module doesn't need to be returned
[Requirejs: Load a module where the require('path/to/module') comes from a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278249/requirejs-load-a-module-where-the-requirepath-to-module-comes-from-a-variab?rq=1)

Comment: Looking at your other question (which you mentioned in your question here) I can't help noticing that you did not mark any of the two answers there as accepted or upvoted either of them and I don't see comments there indicating why these answers failed to help you. Given that the two questions are related (as you yourself point out), it would help answerers to *this* question here if you could explain what it is that the the answers to *that* other question failed to address in *that* question. You know, so that people who answer *this* one don't repeat the same mistake(s).

Comment: The related topic covers how to load modules where theirs paths are coming from variables but doesn't cover how to load and return the module that have their own dependencies. For example, my workaround explains that very well. returning A inside   "require([DEPENDENCY_PATH], function(DEPENDENCY_MODULE){" is ok but the return values is never returned from the module. 
So, when i do var MODULE_A = new module_A(); i got undefined at the mainmodule.